# Azure Synapse Studio ServerLess SQL Pool Access Error

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am not able to access any of my Server Less SQL Pool in Azure Synapse.  I can create new Spark Pool but not SQL Pool.

```
Error is  : 
**You don't have access to the serverless SQL pool, Built-in. To be granted access, contact a Synapse Administrator for this workspace.**
```

When I look back my access privileges, I am the **owner of the Azure Synapse Workspace** and I do have contributor access too. Simultaneously,  I am the "**SQL Active Directory admin**

Additionally  I do have "**Storage Blob Data Contributor**" to access the storage account.

how do ensure thatI have access to BuiltIn ServerLess SQL Pool ?

Additionally, when I open Synapse Studio I can see following pop error.  Any advise, please?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Synapse Team is constantly updating the [Synapse RBAC/privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-workspace-synapse-rbac-roles) feature. The IAM in Azure is for the resource itself. You'll need to check the Workspace RBAC inside the Synapse Studio:

[image]

At present, you'll need either *Synapse Administrator* or *Synapse SQL Administrator* role to access the Serverless SQL pool.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was really struggling as I kept getting the same error:

You don't have access to the serverless SQL pool, Built-in. To be granted access, contact a Synapse Administrator for this workspace.

Comment: Actually having synapse administrator was not enough.  I had to also grant the synapse Sql  administrator role.